# htaccess 301 redirect in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

How can I 301 redirect this with htaccess?

```
http://example.com/category/produkter_and_service
```

to

```
http://example.com/products
```

While not affecting posts within the categories like this:

```
http://example.com/category/produkter_and_service/ventiler-og-bakkekraner/
```

I tried like this:

```
Redirect 301 /category/produkter_and_service http://www.example.com/products
```

But it also affects the posts pages inside like:

```
/category/produkter_and_service/some_product
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect directive matchs the full uri string,  You need to use RedirectMatch instead :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/produkter_and_service$ http://www.example.com/products
```